# Android LinkedIn without LinkedIn SDK

Tags: android, linkedin-api

I want to use LinkedIn in my Android application. I am not sure whether it is right/doable or not but I want to integrate it without LinkedIn SDK. I meant to say, whenever user clicks on login button it should go to the web using webview and user will login there and it should come back. Then I should be able to access the minimal user information.

Just wanted to know whether it is possible or not!

Thank you

Comment: I'd recommend using the linkedin sdk

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply, but is there any way that I can open a webview and user logs in. ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible but you end up with a few issues.

- [If your app becomes successful you increase the chance of having expensive conversations with LinkedIn lawyers.](https://betanews.com/2016/08/16/linkedin-sues-data-scrapers/)
- [Essentially you'd be using a very unofficial and undocumented api which would be subject to change at any time.](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=linkedin%20terms%20and%20conditions%20web%20scraping&oq=linkedin%20terms%20and%20conditions%20web%20scraping&aqs=chrome..69i57.1514j0j9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

If you're doing the project for yourself as research project or for your own internal business use then what you're looking for is to communicate between your native app and the webpage.

See [search google with android javascript communicate with web page view](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=android%20javascript%20communicate%20with%20web%20page%20view&oq=android%20javascript%20communicate%20with%20web%20page%20view&aqs=chrome..69i57.1374j0j9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)